# System cannot find the path specified rename file

Tags: php, file-rename

I am trying to rename a file but I get this error.

```
$newFile = "$surname _$firstname _$dob";
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $newFile);
rename($filename, "$string.pdf");
```

This code produces this error

```
Warning: rename(0001_D_A.pdf,Mccoy_Edward_11/22/2016.pdf): The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3) in C:\xampp\htdocs\script.php on line 7
```

However if I change the code to use a normal string without a variable it will rename the file without any error.

```
$newFile = "$surname _$firstname _$dob";
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $newFile);
rename($filename, "helloworld");
```

The output from $string is -

```
Mccoy_Edward_11/22/2016
```

Answer (score 1):

The `/` in the date are invalid for file names and are interpreted as directory separators by the function.
Use `-` instead to separate the date parts i.e. mm-dd-yyyy

```
$newFile = "{$surname}_{$firstname}_{$dob}";
$string = str_replace('/', '-', $newFile);
rename($filename, "$string.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the slashes are invalid characters in a windows file name (they act as directory separators on unix-like systems). You have to replace them with something valid, e.g. underscores:
`$string = str_replace('/', '_', $newFile);`

Comment: That's not right, forward slashes are not allowed in windows file names, s. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx (or try it yourself). Windows uses backslashes `\\` as directory separator.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean.